# Cordova Plugin Development: Prevent escaping of parameters passed in the plugin

Tags: c#, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I am currently developing a cordova plugin in C#. It should implement an AJAX-call to a server, that uses Basic Authentication. You'll find the [plugin source code here](http://pastebin.de/37428).

As long as I hardcode the username, the password and the url into the plugin everything works fine, or at least as expected. However if I pass the IP, the port and the password in the function as parameters it does not work anymore.

The cordova-documentation states that the parameters have to be deserialize by the JsonHelper - which is what I'm doing. However there must be some kind of problem, as the parameters I pass into the plugin using JavaScript should in theory produce the same url, but the call fails and the debugger shows:

> The remote server returned an error -> File not found.

Here is the JS-bit I use to call the plugin:

```
cordova.exec(win, fail, "BasicAuth", "get", [data.ip, data.port, data.username, data.password]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: Yes, I could implement this AJAX-call in JavaScript, however there is a bug in cordova or the mobile IE (not quite sure which), that leads to a crash of the app, if the wrong credentials are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you should use JSON.stringify(), or similar function:

```
cordova.exec(win, fain, "Plugin", "method", [JSON.stringify(data)]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error was somewhere different though. For those wondering about similiar problems look for blanks.